# how to reference the path to a DTD value in XML

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, dtd, dtd-parsing

I am a newbie when it comes to XML and DTD values, so forgive me if this is a simple question or if I am going about this in the wrong way.  Can you specify a DTD value in the same way you can specify a path to a property in XML?

For instance, if you have the XML file below:

```
<!DOCTYPE ... SYSTEM "<path_to_file>">
<BOOK>
    <AUTHOR>
        <FIRST>John</FIRST>
        <LAST>Quncy</LAST>
    </AUTHOR>
    <NAME>blah</NAME>
    <DATE>12/23/13</DATE>
</BOOK>
```

You could specify the first name of the author by the path:

```
/BOOK/AUTHOR/FIRST
```

Is there any syntax to specify a DTD entity like the DOCTYPE in the same way?

Ultimately what I would like to do is use an in house XML parser already written in java to find a DTD entry that I specify and delete it from the XML file.  For instance, with the above XML, I would like to specify DOCTYPE and have it removed from the XML.  There is already code in place that, given a path, will delete that section from the XML file.  I would like to leverage that to also delete DTD entries as well, but I have no idea how to reference it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `DOCTYPE` is a parsing and validation directive. That is: `DOCTYPE` and `DTD` affect parsing and validation but are not a part of the document as separate entities after that. The XML data model does not contain`DOCTYPE` or `DTD` definitions and they practically don't exist after the document has been parsed.

Comment: Thanks!  That helps a lot in my understanding of DTD and DOCTYPE